# how to store azure function app logs from python logging module?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-application-insights, azure-blob-storage, python-logging

I am working on a first-time project on Azure. We have created Azure Functions apps written in python.

I would like to know how to store my app logs in blob storage. Just to clarify, ***I mean the logs I have written in my code using python's logging module, not the logs Azure collects automatically***. In particular, I would like to store ***the same (live) logs I can see in log stream*** to some blob storage.

Thanks so much in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you  [PierreLucGiguere-5297](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/pierrelucgiguere-5297/). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

- Azure Functions offers an integration with Azure Monitor Logs to monitor functions. You can configure Azure Functions to send system-generated and user-generated logs to Azure Monitor Logs.
- Instead of sending it to "log analytics" you can archive it to a "storage account". For that you need a client tool that works with [Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorers).

You can refer to [How to send Azure Function App logs to Blob Storage?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/544474/how-to-send-azure-function-app-logs-to-blob-storag.html),  [Azure Functions Python developer guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python?tabs=azurecli-linux%2Capplication-level#logging) and [Azure Blob storage bindings for Azure Functions overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob)